# Understanding Stokes' theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Stokes' theorem( here I am only talking about the special $\mathbb{R}^3$ case) contains a line integral $\int_{\partial S} \langle f, \tau \rangle ds$.
(Actually, I would be confident if somebody could explain me the meaning of this integral and how it is defined ) If you can do this, then you do not even have to read the rest of the question :-)

The problem is I have never seen this $ds$ before.
Why don't people write on both sides of the integral the surface measure $dS$? Wouldn't this be more mathematical precise( sure in that case you need to look at $\partial S$ as a 1-dimensional submanifold as we are talking about a curve)?

As I was told in the comment section, $ds$ is also a surface measure but (as far as I understood it now) a different one than $dS$, which is why people use different notation, probably in order to stress that we are talking about two different submanifolds(the curve and the surface).

But in that case ( I assume ) if $\gamma(t)$ is a chart of the curve, by definition of the surface measure we should have $\int_{\partial S} \langle f, \tau \rangle ds = \int_0^{t'}\langle f(\gamma(t)), \tau(\gamma(t)) \rangle ||\gamma'(t)||_2 dt$ is this correct? Am I interpreting right, what $ds$ does?

Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, no one has confirmed my result so far, so I would highly appreciate it if anybody could approve what I have written down so far.

Comment: But you're not measuring a surface. You're measuring along a line, which is more like a distance.

Comment: but isn't measuring the length of a line not just the "area" of a line? I mean, afaik, a line integral is just a special case of a general surface integral.

Comment: Yes, they are parallel concepts. But they are not the same. $dS$ literally returns an area, not a length. And so it would be much less precise. $dt$ literally returns a length, not an area.

Comment: I don't see your point: a curve is just a 1-dim manifold, so why doesn't dS work in this case?

Comment: You cannot both ask about mathematical precision and be imprecise. You are using $\partial S$ to mean the boundary of $S$, and thus $dS$ means the area of $S$. This is a good and precise notation. You are not calculating with this area, and thus should not use the measure $dS$.

Comment: but I could also look at $\partial S$ as a submanifold itself?

Comment: Look, what I don't understand is the following: If you have a curve $\gamma$ then you define $\text{Length(curve)}:=\int_{\gamma} dS(x):= \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \sqrt{g(t)} dt = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} ||\gamma'(t)|| dt$ and this is a perfect definition of the length of a curve. So my idea was to regard $\partial S$ as such a curve and therefore one could apply the surface measure in this case too. Where am I wrong about this?

Comment: You could apply the surface measure if you use $\delta$ functions but it would just reduce to what you have written.

Comment: @Spencer sorry, I don't understand your comment. Are you referring to my last post?

Comment: The set $\partial S$ has measure $0$ in $S$. If you naivily applied  $\int_{\partial S} dS$ to this set you would get $0$. Dirac $\delta$ functions are a way of giving the subset a nonzero meausure in S.

Comment: yeah, but my point was NOT to look at $\partial S$ as a subset of $S$ but to look at it as a curve, which is a manifold by itself and in case that this does not work out. What is the definition of $ds$?

Comment: I saw your point above. What you have been SAYING is that the submanifold should have the same measure as the original manifold which is not the case. In the notation you initially provided for stokes theorem $ds$ is the measure of the submanifold. In practice its exact form depends on the metric of your space. In your example above $ds = \vert \dot{\gamma} \vert dt$ is appropriate.

Comment: so you are saying that I am right and that it is the surface measure, but it is a different surface measure as the one for $S$ so I am supposed to use different notation for this surface measure?

Comment: Yes, if the surface measure $dS$ were the same for both integrals then the integral over $\partial S$ would always be $0$ (which means the equality wouldn't hold). The theorem requires that you use a different measure from $dS$ which would be $ds$,  I suppose you could call this a $1-surface$ measure. If you are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the euclidean metric then $ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$ though this form would change if the metric were different. What you have written will be consistent with this.

Comment: okay, now I understand the thing with the measure. is the way I have expressed the line integral in terms of an ordinary "Riemann"-integral correct too, if the parametrization is given by $\gamma$?

Comment: It looks good to me but there is a subscript $2$ on the norm of $\gamma$ could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: It might be easier if I send you a link for clarification: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-norm#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions    thank you very much by the way

Answer (score 1):

$s$ represents arclength along the curve $\partial S$. This is a *line integral* along the boundary, not a surface integral. Your formula in terms of a parametrization (not chart) is correct.

Comment: yes, but is the representation of the integral that I have written down there correct or incorrect? (cause this is my understanding of a line integral)

Comment: I just said it was! :) Perhaps you wrote while I was editing.

Comment: ah okay, perfect! Just out of curiosity: When I am reading your answer I see that you suggest the following: Since this is a line integral you cannot use there $dS$ cause this suggests that you are integrating over a surface, right? My point was that $dS$ represents the surface measure and since a closed line is a submanifold (1 dimensional) (of course the surface itself is a 2d submanifold in this case) in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I would have thought that it would be completely okay to write a $dS$ instead of a $ds$. Can you explain to me, why my reasoning is incorrect?

Comment: We use different notations according to the dimension, mostly to avoid these confusions!

Comment: I see, but my perception is not wrong in principle?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what your point is.

Comment: Okay again: This $dS$ is the so-called surface measure, which is defined in the context of integration on submanifolds. Therefore, $dS$ is not restricted to integration on surfaces in the three-dimensional space but rather to every integration on a submanifold. A closed curve is also such a submanifold, which is why it would be okay to write $dS$ in a line integral as it is a 1-dimensional submanifold.

Comment: Not the notational convention in place in a beginning calculus course, exactly because it confuses people. But any $k$-dimensional submanifold of a Riemannian manifold inherits a $k$-dimensional "area" measure. It's probably best to have a subscript that specifies the dimension.

Comment: Alright, but again: $ds$ means also surface(or area) measure, but we do not write $dS$ in order to simplify notation, right?

Comment: Yikes. No. $ds$ means *specifically* and *only* arclength measure for a curve.

Comment: but how is this different from the area measure that a curve inherits?(as you said, a 1-d submanifold inherits a 1-d "area" measure and this measure is your arclength measure, isn't it?)

Comment: By the way: Thank you for helping me with this.

Comment: do you see what I am talking about? I do not see the difference between the 1d area measure for 1d submanifolds and the arclength measure.